# Solve task using Identity theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

So we got two harmonic functions $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ on $D$. They agree in the neighborhood of some point $(x_0,y_0)$ $\in D$. Prove that they agree on whole set D.

how can I get from harmonic functions to analytic, in order to use Identity theorem?
I don't know u and v are conjugate or not. I believe there was some theorem which stated that in open connected set function u has harmonic conjugate, but how can i be sure that this conjugate is function v?

Comment: $u$ and $v$ will have harmonic conjugates so that the corresponding analytic functions $f_u, f_v$ have real parts equal to $u,v$ respectively. Since $f_u-f_v=0$ on a neighbourhood it must be zero on the $D$ (assuming $D$ is connected).

Comment: @copper.hat why  $f_u−f_v=0$ ?. they have different harmonic conjugates

Comment: Sorry, I mean to write that $f_u -f_v$ is purely imaginary, hence constant.